# Exporting a Dyminics CRM Report to excel with sum fields

Tags: excel, reporting-services, dynamics-crm

Hi I created a custom report for CRM in SSRS. 
within this report I have some number (decimal) fields that are summed.

I need to be able to export this report to Excel to allow for changes (some times the user needs to make custom changes to the data) but I need the sum fields on the group to actually be a formula field so that it is updated as the user edits the excel data.

Is this possible with the export to Excel option?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speaking to a developer friend, this is not possible as a standard export from the report. Additional Macros have to be written to enable the kind of functionality i was looking for.